# Move resource with Nginx rewrite/redirect

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I have a node app running on http://localhost:3000. I set up ssl/https with LetsEncrypt so all requests are 301 redirected to https. Im using Nginx as web server.

I'm trying to move my URL from `resume.mydomain.com` to `mydomain.com/resume`.

How do I forward requests to `mydomain.com` AND `mydomain.com/resume` to my node app?
If users go to `mydomain.com` AND `resume.mydomain.com` they should automatically be redirected to `mydomain.com/resume`.

How do I do this?